# WPF slider thumb.DragCompleted

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I'm learning from Mark Heath course of NAudio.
I'm  using a slider with the event:

```
Thumb.DragCompleted="SilderPositionOnDragCompleted"
```

And in the c#:

```
private void SilderPositionOnDragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb.DragCompleted e)
    {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(slider.Value);
            }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that I wrote wrong the:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb.DragCompleted
```

Because I have no idea what I need to write in there - I saw this here in the site.

are the errors:
[image: Here]

What do I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void SilderPositionOnDragCompleted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (reader != null)
    {
        reader.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(slider.Value);
    }
}
```

The type of the second argument should be `RoutedEventArgs`.

And if you are hooking up the event handler programmatically you should use the following syntax:

```
Thumb.DragCompleted += SilderPositionOnDragCompleted;
```

...where "Thumb" is the name of your Thumb:

```
<Thumb x:Name="Thumb" />
```

Or

```
Thumb Thumb = ...;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It fixed 1 error but I still got the error "No overload for 'SilderPositionOnDragCompleted' matches delegate "

Comment: Could you please post the full XAML markup/code where you hook up the event handler then?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYv0q.png
Its too long for copying it so here is the picture

Comment: Yes sorry i didn't pay attention i changed the link

Comment: See my edit and post the code if you need any further help.

Comment: I closed visual studio and its working now haha.
Thanks a lot!